# X forwarding application shows blank window after one successful load

Tags: macos, ssh, java, x11

I'm running into a strange issue trying to forward an application from a remote Linux server over X (through ssh).

The application (it is a java application---a commercial program, not my own) seems to load successfully once, but after exiting and trying to run it again I only get a blank X11 window, with the correct application title. I don't get any errors, the window just doesn't load.

My `.ssh\config` options for both servers include ForwardX11 and ForwardX11Trusted.

I'm running OS X 10.9, with XQuartz 2.7.5. One machine I'm trying to run this application from is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, and the other is RHEL 6.4.

Any ideas, or suggestions on where to look for an issue? I've tried ssh'ing with `-vvv`, but I didn't notice any obvious error messages.